# Laravel - exception must be an instance of dompdf

Tags: php, laravel, exception, dompdf

Using laravel (5.4) I set up a job handler and a failed handler for queued jobs. But for some reason when the job fails and the fail handler should be called and the exception passed to it, I am getting:

> [2017-09-04 13:50:31] local.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Jobs\TransferSearchImage::failed() must be an instance of Dompdf\Exception, instance of GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException given, called in /srv/cr/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php on line 98 in /srv/cr/app/Jobs/TransferSearchImage.php:91

The job handler function reads:

```
    /**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{
    $this->logFunction();

    // get and build token
    $apiTokenType = 'Bearer';
    $apiTokenCode = env('SEARCH_API_KEY');
    $apiToken = $apiTokenType . ' ' . $apiTokenCode;

    // get uri
    $uri = env('SEARCH_TRANSFER_URI') . 'a';

    Log::Debug('apiToken: ' . $apiToken);
    Log::Debug('searchid: ' . $this->transferData['searchid']);
    Log::Debug('base64: ' . $this->transferData['base64']);

    // build headers
    $headers = [
        'Authorization' => $apiToken,
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Accept-Encoding' => 'application/json',
        'X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest'
    ];

    // encode data for body
    $body = \GuzzleHttp\json_encode($this->transferData);

    // make request
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;
    $request = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('POST', $uri, $headers, $body);
    $response = $client->send($request, ['timeout' => 10]);
    $status = $response->getStatusCode();
    $data = json_decode( (string) $response->getBody() );

    Log::Debug('status: ' . $status);

}
```

And the failed handler function:

```
    /**
 * The job failed to process.
 *
 * @param  Exception  $exception
 * @return void
 */
public function failed(Exception $exception)
{
    // Send user notification of failure, etc...
}
```

I even added

> use Exception;

to the class but no change. Also tried prefixing a \ but no success either. How can I submit any kind of Exception to the failed handler?

Comment: check what the `Exception` class stand for in your class? may be use have something like `use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException as Exception`

Comment: I've found that when I'm working with Jobs and I make a change that doesn't seem to be having any effect, it's usually because I didn't restart the queue. What happens is while the queue is running, any classes that were loaded are stored in memory for as long as the queue runs, so your changes will be ignored until the queue is shut down, that memory is cleared, and the queue restarts. Maybe give that a quick try?

Comment: Ok this pointed me to the right direction. The problem was the cached autoload. Afte issuing a **composer dump-autoload** the Dompdf\Exception was no longer a problem and the correct common Exception Class used.